# e-mail validation rule in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am doing validation this way.

```
$rules = [ 
  'email'=> 'required|regex:/^.+@.+$/i|unique:tab_example,email,'.$this>get('example_id').',example_id'
];

return $rules;
```

However, I am not getting success.

The error informs that

> the email already exists

What I want is that if the **email already exists** and is from the same user does not need to inform that the email already exists.

I do not know what the problem is in my code.

Comment: from the same user how?

Comment: where do you implement this code? in controller ?

Comment: there is a user registration, when you open his or her registration and send this same registration if the e-mail is not exchanged, the e-mail remains linked to this user, ie you do not need to show that this e-mail already is being used because it is the same user.

Comment: I created a request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
$this->route('example_id')
```

instead of

```
$this>get('example_id')
```

And if you use resource route then use $this->route('user').

```
  $rules = [ 
       'email'=> 'required|regex:/^.+@.+$/i|unique:tab_example,email,'.$this->route('example_id').',example_id'
   ];

   return $rules;
```

Comment: I did this, but still it returns me the same problem, it says that the email already exists ...

Comment: what is your parameter name ? and did you use resource route ?

Comment: public function rules()
      {          $rules = [    'email' => "required|unique:tab_example,email,".$this->route('example_id').",example_id"       ]; return $rules;                                      }

Comment: I am not talking about your rules function. I am talking about your route. can you give your relevant route ?

Comment: my problem is to get user id, I do not know if I'm getting it wrong, but I realized this, I think the problem might be with route (). My routes: $ this-> post ('/ admin / doctors / save / {id?}', 'MedicosController @ save') -> name ('doctors'); $ this> any ('/ admin / doctors / {action?} / {id?}', 'MedicosController @ action') -> name ('doctors');

Comment: Your validation looks good to me. If you update your code like i suggested. i am using it in my project and it working fine. thanks

Comment: I solved the problem. I just got the id like this: 'med_email' => Rule :: unique ('tab_medicos') -> ignore (request () -> route ('id'), 'med_id'), Thanks friend, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
'email' => "required|email|unique:users,email,{$id},id",
```

The id should be replaced with the primary key column name of the table you use for the unique check. The {$id} should be defined before `$rules` array like:

```
$id = $request->route('user')
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I think the last value (i.e. `id`) is not required https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-unique

Comment: The last two will be used for 'unique except $id from id column' (on update)

Comment: Yes, but the second to last (`$id`)  is the id specifation and laravel will look by default at the `id` column, so the last one is not required here

Comment: Absolutely! I included it because the question owner included `$this>get('example_id').',example_id'`

Comment: Ah yes i missed that :) nvm then

Comment: 'email' => "required|unique:tab_example,email,".$this->route('id_example').",id_example" is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, you may wish to ignore a given ID during the unique check.

For example, consider an **"update profile"** screen that includes the user name, e-mail address, and location. Of course, you will want to verify that the e-mail address is unique.

However, if the user only changes the name field and not the e-mail field, you do not want a validation error to be thrown because the user is already the owner of the e-mail address.

you can use like:

```
'email' => [
        'required',
         Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
'email' => Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id, 'user_id');
```

[Read Under the Section Forcing A Unique Rule To ignore A given Field](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-unique)

Answer (score 1):

Try This way

```
$rules = [ 
        'email'=> ['required', 'email', \Illuminate\Validation\Rule::unique('tab_example', 'email')->whereNot('example_id',$this->get('example_id'))]
    ];
```